rstudio translate column content and column name to another language
How to use library(googleLanguageR) or similar to translate the following data table (both the header name and the column)? Dt is the starting point and DT_end what I would expect.
DT <- data.table(frase=c('Buongiorno','rosso','sera'))

DT_end <- data.table(sentence=c('Buongiorno','rosso','sera'),
                 sentence=c('good morning','red','evening'))
DT_end

